# linq Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQuerable

Tags: linq

I have the following query:

```
    tblVAL tblval = db.tblVALs.Where(p => p.PID == pid);
```

Note that I expect to get a list of items that should be returned.
tblVAL is a table in Entity Framework. NOTE THAT I NEED A LIST OF ITEMS TO BE RETURNED AS THERE CAN BE MORE THAN 1 ITEMS THAT IS RETURNS. AS SUCH, I DO NOT WANT TO USE First(), etc.

I get the following message

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQuerable to wa.Models.tblVAL'. An implicit converion exist (are you missing a cast? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is returning a collection. You need to call [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault.aspx), `Single`, `First`, or `FirstOrDefault` to get a single record.

```
tblVAL tblval = db.tblVALs.Where(p => p.PID == pid).SingleOrDefault();
```

If you want a collection, change your variable type to a collection:

```
IEnumerable<tblVAL> tblval = db.tblVALs.Where(p => p.PID == pid);
```

You can also call `ToList` to force query execution:

```
List<tblVAL> tblval = db.tblVALs.Where(p => p.PID == pid).ToList();
```

Comment: I need it to return a collection. How do I make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get many results back, the simple thing to do is to call ToList.

Become familiar with the methods of [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) and you will be an expert at linq.